# CodeBlocks Module Definition File

Tags: windows, winapi, linker, codeblocks

How i can add / insert my .def file into project in CodeBlocks? --def=file.def don't work. I was try added .def file into linker, but it don't help me. Compiler returns error about --def isn't recognized command or compile code without .def file.

Comment: What modules are you talking about? C++20 modules?

Comment: About .dll file, which i import with LoadLibrary, but it is compiled file and i haven't source code, so i can't add dllexport into file and i have do this with .def file

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This dll file use c++14

Comment: No. A def file is used whe you compile a library and wish to list the exported symbols. You don't use it when importing a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already generate the dll without .def file or "dllexport" declaration. You are not able to import the function symbols. 
Read the doc from msdn [Exporting from a DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll?view=vs-2019), The method of export functions with module definition (.def) file is:

> Create a module definition (.def) file and **use the .def file when
>   building the DLL.**